# Main thread: can runnables be preempted?

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, runnable, android-handler

I've a runnable instance that self-schedules itself again at the end of its `run` method:

```
    private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        private volatile boolean cancelled = false;
        private Handler handler;

        public MyRunnable(Handler h){
            handler = h;
        }


        @Override
        public void run(){
            //Do stuff
            if(!cancelled){
                //Preemtion possible here?
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }

        public void selfStart(){
            cancelled = false;
            handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            handler.post(this);
        }

        public void selfCancel(){
            cancelled = true;
            handler.removeCallbacks(this);
        }
    }
```

The runnable is first **scheduled in the main thread** calling `selfStart` from an activity's `onStart`.

At the same time, the runnable can be externally cancelled (calling `selfCancel`) from the activity's `onStop` and also from a Broadcast Receiver.

AFAIK `Runnable.run`, `Activity.onStop` and `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive` run in the same thread (the main one), so at first glance I thought there would be no thread-safety issues.

But it looks like sometimes, the runnable is being preemted in the middle of its `run` call, then it is cancelled from the activity or receiver, and then it resumes and re-schedules itself again.

Is this possible?

---

UPDATE:
I'll try to explain better the issue. The class shown above is intended to run tasks periodically in the main thread. In the "do stuff" comment there's actually code that updates a `TextView` with a value passed to the `MyRunnable` constructor. The activity cancels the current runnable and starts a new one when certain intents are received. Despite the current runnable is always requested to cancel itself before the new one is created, sometimes it is being left running along with the new one, so the text view is showing alternating values. This is not the intended behavior.

I thought if the runnable was currently running in the main thread, it would run until completion, and then other runnables or event handlers would be taken out of the queue and executed if needed, but no pending event or runnable could be "half executed".

There are two kinds of tasks running in the main thread that are related to the problem:

- R1: The `MyRunnable` self-scheduling task. Runs and then it self-posts itself again with a delay of 1s.
- R2: The event handlers that request cancellation of the current `MyRunnable` instance and create a new R1'. These happen randomly and are executed only once.

I've contemplated two scenarios. The first one:

1. R1 is already running in the main thread.
2. R2 arrives and is enqueued in the main thread.
3. R1 finishes running and posts itself again.
4. R2 runs and removes callbacks for R1.
5. R1 should never run again.

And the second one:

1. R1 is not running but is scheduled.
2. R2 arrives and removes callbacks for R1.
3. R1 should never run again.

Theoretically, if there's no preemtion, and there's only a single thread, how comes sometimes there are two R1s in the main thread?

Comment: if you post your Runnable to only one Looper, that what you describe is not possible

Comment: how do you know the runnable is preemted on the line you marked? Is it possible it performs handler.post(this) and then ends its current run?

Comment: @user3118604 I don't think it is preempted, that is the only possible explanation I can find when there's a single thread. But sounds far-fetched and I don't want to believe it is even possible.

Comment: The idea that a method running on a thread might be pre-empted by something else on that thread is hard to credit.  More plausible might be that each method once begun runs to completion before anything else on that thread, but that *the queue of methods to be called is not being managed in the way you expect*.  Logging the entry and return of each method with its tid should provide insight - you should never see a new method begin on a thread before the current one has returned.

Answer (score 1):

As you have no synchronization on selfStart or selfCancel this is entirely possible.

An unreleated note, `selfCancel` could be called on a separate thread after your if statement in your run method has checked the value of `cancelled`. `MyRunnable` would then get one more call to run, which would end immediately as it's been cancelled.

Comment: While this would be true if multiple threads were involved, this is not really a meaningful answer to the question asked, unless you explain why some of this code would be running on a thread other than the main / UI thread.

Comment: There's no separate thread. All scheduling or cancellations are being called in the main thread. Synchronized on those methods wont change much, because `selfStart` is only called once when the app starts. The problematic methods are `selfCancel` and `run`. I think `selfCancel`is being called when the run method is inside the flag check.

Comment: @MisterSmith - that's not possible if only one thread is involved.  Why don't you add some logging of the thread utilized to each method?

Comment: If your object wasn't being manipulated by more than one thread, this wouldn't be happening. So, try synchronizing your object, or track down the second thread.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Agree. Logging was added recently but to no avail. This issue is really difficult to reproduce, and unfortunately the only cases I know about were versions without logging, so I'll have to figure out just by reading the code. I've updated the question with a better explanation anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to move the `//Do stuff` inside the canceled check.

This avoids the race regardless of assumptions about which thread things are running on.

```
    @Override
    public void run(){
        if(!cancelled){
            //Do stuff
            handler.post(this);
        }
    }
```

In general for maintainability, try to write code that works correctly regardless of the thread it is being run on. You never know when somebody will call selfCancel() on some other thread later thinking it is okay, when you have assumed they won't do that.

Comment: In my particular case it does not really matter if the "stuff" runs after cancellation, but anyway thanks for the advice. And no one, never ever will call `selfCancel` from another thread, that's guaranteed :) It is explicitly mentioned in the docs.

Comment: LOL. Because putting it in the docs means that future developers are sure to read the docs.

Comment: There's probably not going to be any other future developer, right now I'm the only one with this. But I changed my mind after posting that comment, and I'm now throwing exceptions if the methods are not called from the main thread.

Comment: Nice. Always good to validate your assumptions in code. Even if you are the only developer, sometimes when you come back to your own code you forgot the assumptions you made when you wrote it and then shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

Well as others have said, there's no way a runnable can be preempted in a single thread. I also thought this idea was absurd. Shame on me for coming up with that nonsense.

There was nothing wrong with the runnables themselves. They were launched in the activity's `onStart`, and cancelled from Intents received by the activity, or in the activity's `onStop`. An this is the root of the problem: assuming `onStart` and `onStop` would run in a predictable order. Sometimes when coming back to the activity, a second `onStart` was executed before the first activity's `onStop`. Two tasks were running and the thing messed up to a point where the first task was never terminated.

Ensuring no task is launched without previous termination of the current one solved the issue.